# generic.edit.CreateView Assign Default Values and Insert Into Database

Tags: python, django, model, django-class-based-views

I have the following class-based view that uses my model to generate a "Create" screen:

```
class ProjectCreateView(generic.edit.CreateView):
    model = Project
    fields = ['project_title','project_description','created_date']
    template_name = 'steps/project-detail.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')
```

Model:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    project_description = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")
    created_date = models.DateTimeField('date created')
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.project_title
```

Now, the problem is that if I do not want the `'created_date'` to be on the actual form. Instead, I would like it to be populated automatically whenever the Submit button is pressed or whenever the record is being added into database. How can I achieve this?

Lastly, is it possible to also specify the `owner` field by default? That is, I need to populate that field with information of the user who is creating this record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leave the `owner` and `created_date` out of your list of fields. Then override `form_valid` and set the values on the form's instance before calling `super()`.

Since you are setting the owner, you can use the [`LoginRequiredMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin) to make sure that only logged-in users can access the view.

```
from datetime import datetime

from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView


class ProjectCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Project
    fields = ['project_title','project_description']
    template_name = 'steps/project-detail.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.owner = self.request.user
        form.instance.created_date = datetime.now()
        return super(ProjectCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: What about using [`auto_now_add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) for the datetime field instead?

Comment: @AKS Yes, using `auto_now_add` in the model field is a good suggestion. In that case, the `form.instance.created_date = datetime.now()` line can be removed from the code.

Comment: How would this look? As in, I get an error if I add auto_now_add into the model.

Comment: Changing the model to `created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)` should work.